# Output not showing up in django framework

Tags: python, html, django

Below is my code! I want to run python script in html, But I can not see the output whenever I execute this! Please help!
Below is my code! I want to run python script in html, But I can not see the output whenever I execute this! Please help!
Below is my code! I want to run python script in html, But I can not see the output whenever I execute this! Please help!Below is my code! I want to run python script in html, But I can not see the output whenever I execute this! Please help!

```js
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
def button(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def output(request):
    data=requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
    print(data.text)
    data=data.text
    return render(request,'home.html',{'data':data})
```

```css
urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.button),
    url(r'^$', views.output, name="script") 

]
```

```html
home.html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Python Script</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="location.href='{% url 'script' %}'">Click Me</button>
<hr>
{% if data %}
{{data | safe}
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will look for the first pattern that matches and fire (only) that view, so in this case it will "fire" `button`, and render the `home.html` *without* any context.